# angular2/4. What for should I use Reactive Forms when there is built in FormsModule?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Can anyone please explain why
I need to use them?

In which cases Reactive Forms make my life simpler and better in comparison with FormsModule?

Comment: I don't think this is really a question for this site, angular have a [blog post here](http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/) that deals with your question. For me I find reactive forms very useful for immutable form values and unit testable form validation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, the `FormsModule` is sufficient if you have very simple requirements.  My first forms were all `FormsModule`. They're great if you just need to bind form inputs to model properties.

`ReactiveFormsModule` are a bigger pain to setup the first time you do it, but they give you much more control. Because you create the form elements in your components, you can easily do things such as:

- read/write the value of the input at any point (even before the view is built)
- Define advanced validation rules, including async validators (eg: check with the server whether the username entered is available while the user is filling out the rest of a registration form)
- Be notified and react immediately when the value change
- Access the native HTML form element
- Reset the form...
- If you care about unit tests (good coders should), reactive forms are significantly easier to test because they can be manipulated imperatively. With `FormsModule`, just getting a reference to the form instance in your unit test is a pain.

Since I made the switch, I haven't gone back to `FormsModule`. [See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms)

> Angular reactive forms facilitate a reactive style of programming that favors explicit management of the data flowing between a non-UI data model (typically retrieved from a server) and a UI-oriented form model that retains the states and values of the HTML controls on screen. Reactive forms offer the ease of using reactive patterns, testing, and validation.
>
> With reactive forms, you create a tree of Angular form control objects in the component class and bind them to native form control elements in the component template, using techniques described in this guide.
>
> You create and manipulate form control objects directly in the component class. As the component class has immediate access to both the data model and the form control structure, you can push data model values into the form controls and pull user-changed values back out. The component can observe changes in form control state and react to those changes.

Comment: Advanced validation can also be implemented with template driven forms through directives

Answer (score 1):

Both Reactive Forms and Forms Module are completely acceptable based on your need.In Reactive Forms(Model Driven Forms) you can define your fields and your validation on your component and wire them in to your html template.It required extra code but it has some advantages.

For example you have more option of building your form and validation more dynamically based on decision made in your code.

And another great benefit is that it makes all of your validation logic unit testable